# What are the differences between "sudo -s" and "su root"?

Tags: sudo, su

What are the differences between "sudo -s" and "su root"?
As they both can provide root permission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a bunch of differences, the main one being that `sudo -s` relies on the user having sudoer privileges whereas `su root` requires the user to have the root password.

**As a side-note**

From a security perspective, it is much better to assign users sudoer privileges to access the root shell rather than passing around a root password that users can use through `su root`. If a user has the root password, they can obtain root anytime. If they are assigned privileges through `/etc/sudoers`, then access to the root shell can be revoked at anytime.